# Pull info from Soundcloud embed into a custom field?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, api, embed

I'm working on a blog that has over 4000 posts. Most of them have a soundcloud embed iframe in the post.

I am creating a new custom field (using Advanced Custom Fields) that uses a custom player using soundclouds API...and i just need the URL of the soundcloud track in a custom field.. NOT the embed info.

Is it possible to scan the blog and retrieve the info from the soundcloud embed and put that into a custom field?

I used ***Display Embedded Videos by D.Biot***, a plugin, that basically did the same thing for youtube.

Any help would be much appreciated!  If you need me to post any code, let me know but i didn't think it was relevant...

----- SOUNDCLOUD GENERIC EMBED------ 
Here is just a random embed from soundcloud.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/212039125&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Everything is Possible [full stop]. You need to know the embed code's pattern first. Then using a SQL Query with `LIKE '%string%'` you can grab the content. For critical embed code you might need [Regular Expression](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). Grabbing the right content and then you need a simple insert SQL or WordPress' [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to insert that information into that Custom Field. But it's too broad to discuss here. :(

Comment: ahh, i don't know, but thank you @MayeenulIslam - i think this is a little over my head.  i've added the soundcloud embed ot the post, if you can help at all clarifying it would be incredible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rudimentary plugin, not tested. It will function once, when the plugin is activated.

- Copy the code
- Make it a file named `__once.php`
- Save the file in `wp-content\plugins\__once\`
- Browse the `wp-admin/plugins.php`, and activate the plugin named **__once**.

> **WARNING:** It's not tested. It's recommended to test first, fix bugs, fix the way it should be for yours, then use it or build your one.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin name: __once
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204002/22728
 * Description: A onetime minimal plugin to update all the postmeta from the content iframes.
 */


/**
 * Grabbing all the posts and populating postmeta.
 * Once, only on this plugin's activation.
 */
function wpse_do_once() {
    $all_posts = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'         => 'any',
            'post_status'       => array( 'publish, pending, draft' ),
            'posts_per_page'    => -1
        )
    );
    while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();
        $post_content = get_the_content();

        //the src information from iframe
        $src = wpse_get_iframe_src( $post_content );

        foreach( $src as $link ) {
            //Populating the custom field
            //Assumed: Your custom field id is '_my_embed_link'
            //this will override the values if there's two or more iframes
            if( !empty() ) {
                update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_embed_link', esc_url( $link ) );
            }
        }


    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_do_once' );

/** HELPER FUNCTION */

/**
 * Grab all iframe src from a string.
 * @author Dbranes
 * @link   http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/10006
 * @param  string $input The content.
 * @return string        The src attribute value.
 */
function wpse_get_iframe_src( $input ) {
    preg_match_all("/<iframe[^>]*src=[\"|']([^'\"]+)[\"|'][^>]*>/i", $input, $output );

    $return = array();

    if( isset( $output[1][0] ) )
        $return = $output[1];

    return $return;
}
```

#### How it works:

It's fetching all the posts of any status from the site, then taking all of the contents, and using a custom function (powered with RegEx) ([source](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/10006)) fetched the src from the iframes. Then puts the src values to the postmeta (aka Custom Field).

Please note the helper function returns an array of src values if there's multiple in a post content. So a single `update_post_meta()` will override one with the other. In that case you can choose avoiding the foreach loop and save the array in a serialized form. Then when showing the field data using `get_post_meta()` you will need to show the individual URL from there.